# React native Flatlist not re-rendering on state change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I realize there are a lot of questions and answers about this out there but I am fairly new to react native and most of the answers are dealing with React Components and not hooks. In the following example availableInterests is pulled from a firestore database call. Then we loop through the availableInterests so the user can select the their interests from the Flatlist of interests. Everything works great except the FLatlist does not re-render so the button that is used to select currentInterests never shows the change that an interest has been selected. Does anyone see what I am missing here?

```
const [availableInterests, setAvailableInterests] = useState([]);
const [currentInterests, setCurrentInterests] = useState([]);
    const selectThisInterest = (item) => {
        let myInterests = currentInterests;
        if(myInterests.includes(item.id)) {
          myInterests.pop(item.id);
        } else {
          myInterests.push(item.id);
        }

        setCurrentInterests(myInterests);
      }

  return <View>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Select Your Interests:</Text>
      <FlatList
       data={availableInterests}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       extraData={currentInterests}
       renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
         <View key={item.id}>
           <Text>{item.title}</Text>
           <Text>{item.description}</Text>
           <Image
            source={{ uri: item.icon }}
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100}}
           />
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selectThisInterest(item)}>
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{`${currentInterests.includes(item.id) ? 'UnSelect' : 'Select'}`}</Text>
           <Text>{item.id}</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      }>
    </FlatList>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the mistake is in your `selectThisInterest` function. When you are updating the `currentInterests` based on previous value, React doesn't recognises such a change because you are simply assigning `myInterests` with your `currentInterests`.

What you want to do is to copy that array and assign it to `myInteresets` and then update your values to the new copied array. Once the calculation are completed on the new `myInteresets` array, the `setCurrentInterests()` will re-render the app because now React recognises there is a change in the state.

To copy the array, you can use,

```js
let myInterests = [...currentInterests];
```

change your `selectThisInterest` function to reflect this change,

```js
const selectThisInterest = (item) => {
  let myInterests = [...currentInterests];
  if(myInterests.includes(item.id)) {
    myInterests.pop(item.id);
  } else {
    myInterests.push(item.id);
  }
  setCurrentInterests(myInterests);
}
```

Comment: This is the one of the most helpful comments on Stack Overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

put this state below

```
const [currentInterests, setCurrentInterests] = useState([]);
const [extra, setExtra] = useState(0);
```

at the end of your function just put this

```
    const selectThisInterest = (item) => {
    ....

    setExtra(extra + 1)
  }
```

Comment: I try this but it still does not change. I thought that because I was changing the state of currentInterests each time that it would cause a refresh. But so far neither of these are doing that.

Comment: Actually, I needed to add extra as the extraData so... extraData={extra}  and then it works. If you want to add that to your answer I will accept as the correct answer. :) I am wondering if the currentInterests changing doesn't force the re-render because it is an array?

Comment: you can use extraData prop and give the state to it

Comment: @Starfs no, because you are using a that state in Flatlist that is already rendered, at-least that is my understanding. anyone are welcome to correct me. As a good practice we were told to add this extra useState so we never raise this question.